# Two concerns on this text regarding "sick" and "up and go"

Tags: word-meaning

> What my family lacked was a father, but a father doll was a true rarity. Nobody I knew had a father doll. Most of the kids I knew didn’t even have fathers. I didn’t have a father; mine died when I was two. My family consisted of my mother, my grandmother, and me. That was perfectly normal. Fathers had a tendency to die, or to lose themselves to alcoholism, or to simply “ **up and go** .” Our next-door neighbor up and went to the Far North one night. He announced his decision by screaming on the staircase, “I’m **sick** of you all!”
>
> “So you’re just gonna up and go, huh? Well, good riddance!” his wife screamed back. But his three-year-old daughter cried for weeks. I could hear her through the thin walls of our apartment.

1. What does it mean **up and go**?
2. Does the word **sick** here mean ** hate and dislike** or **angry** . they say **I am sick and tired of you** and that means **I am angry with you** .

Answer (score 1):

> •up and do something:
>
> to do something suddenly or unexpectedly He upped and went, pausing
>   only to thank us with a gracious bow.

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/up_80

For the meaning of 'sick of', see definition #3 here: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sick#sick

Answer (score 1):

*Up and go* simply means go away without notifying anyone (may or maynot be to get rid of responsibility). Another such use I remember is from the [MJ song 'Who is it?](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/michaeljackson/whoisit.html)'. He sings, *"And She Didn't Leave A Letter She Just Up And Ran Away."*

*sick of* simply means [tired of or fed up of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sick+of).